# Why an empty space is stored in the first cell of Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Can some body explain why an empty space is stored in first cell of my String Array? I am trying to store each line inputted through console into a String array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassNameHere {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numberOfLines = in.nextInt();

      String[] lines = new String[numberOfLines];      

      for( int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++ ){
          lines[i] = in.nextLine();            
      }

      for( int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++ ){
          System.out.println(lines[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Plz post your code along with the question

Comment: It is taking the number as  a first input because of this you are getting first one is empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in.nextInt()` reads only the int value not the newline character after that. So that newline will be read by your `in.nextLine()` so your first index is empty. To eliminate this problem  add a dummy `in.nextLine()` after reading the `int`.

```
int numberOfLines = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
```

Another method is to use `nextLine()` instead of `nextInt()` to read the and parse the input to `int`.

```
int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Comment: Last idea gives an error "int cannot be converted to a string". Thanks for the better explaination!!

Comment: @Raj44 plz try that again I dont think it would give an error.

Comment: @Raj44 replace this line `int numberOfLines = in.nextInt();` with `int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());` and dont add that `in.nextLine()`

Answer (score 1):

After you call `in.nextInt()`, the first call to `in.nextLine()` returns the rest of that same line, and therefore it's empty.

You should add a call to `in.nextLine()` before the loop to consume that empty line.

```
      int numberOfLines = in.nextInt();

      String[] lines = new String[numberOfLines];      

      in.nextLine(); // add this
      for( int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++ ){
          lines[i] = in.nextLine();            
      }

      for( int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++ ){
          System.out.println(lines[i]);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for you.

```
int numberOfLines = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine(); //Add this.
```

`in.nextInt();` reads the integer value and then you click enter which is read by `in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code is

```
// this reads a number, not the new line after the number
int numberOfLines = in.nextInt();
// reads the rest of the first line you typed.
lines[i] = in.nextLine();
```

If you want to ignore the rest of the line after the number, add `in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nextLine() instead of int numberOfLines = in.nextInt();

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because method `nextInt()` reads only the number (3) and the `newline` that follows is picked up by the first call to `nextLine()`.